# Choco-Solver: Is there a way to know how many times a constraint is broken during the solving process?

Tags: java, constraints, constraint-programming, choco

My models is inefficient and taking too long to find valid solutions so I think knowing how many times the constraints are being broken would be useful for testing.

Thank you

Comment: You mean in regards to multiple constraints/propagators? I don't think this information is useful / kept as this is hard to interpret. If you have 10 constraints, 9 with simple propagators, 1 with an alldiff, most engines will propagate the 9 cheap ones first and it might be hard to read out something useful here. Did you try the more obvious/simple things as looking on *nodes / backtracking* statistics (should be there somehow) and playing with different search-strategies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since Choco-solver-4.10.8, it is possible to have insights on the propagation.

```java
//...
Solver s = m.getSolver();
PropagationProfiler profiler = s.profilePropagation();
s.findSolution();
profiler.writeTo(new File("profiling.txt"));
```

You can have an idea of what is being collected in the [following discussion](https://github.com/chocoteam/choco-solver/discussions/832).